# boolean algebra and simplify boolean expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, boolean-algebra

question1: 
from =$ab+ac+a'b'c$ , can I change it to $ab+b'c$ ?

=$ab+ac+a'b'c$ 
=$c.!(a+a'b')+ab$ -> applied demorgan, am I right? 
=$c(a'.(a+b))+ab$ 
$c(a'a+a'b)+ab$ 
$a'bc+ab$ 
$b(a'c+a)$ ->should I apply demorgan again? , but after I apply it, I didn't get
$ab+b'c$
 
is this true??

question 2:

Boolean algebra :

=$AB+A'B+AB'$
=A(B+B')+B(A+A') -> why $A'B$ changed to B(A+A') , what law is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

*Question $1$*: Note we can write $ac +a’b’c =c(a+a’b’)$. Now use absorption law.

*Question $2$*: Note that $AB+A’B+AB’=AB+AB+A’B+AB’=A(B+B’)+B(A+A’)$.

Comment: thanks! for number 1, $c.(a+a'b')+ab$ then can I apply demorgan theorem?  =$ c.!(a+a'b')+ab$ = $ c(a'.(a+b))+ab$= $c(a'a+a'b)+ab$ like what I wrote above? if using absorbtion law $c(a+a'b')+ab$ the variables inside the bracket and outside are different. how can I do it? $(c+0)(a'a+a'b)+ab$ tried this but not working.

Comment: Note that the absorption law: $a+a’b’=a+b’$ Then we will have $c(a+b’)+ab= \, ?$, @Vixf

Comment: @Vixf, you can accept my answer if it helped you by ticking the green mark.

Comment: how can you changed it into this $a+a’b’=a+b’$ ? $(a+a')+a'b'$? I've never applied absorbtion theorem to $a+a'b'$, usually there is atleast one variable same in order to apply the theorem(?) and can I use demorgan theorem to simplify it to?

Comment: i got it!. but $ac+cb'+ab$ = $c(a+b')+ab$ = $ac+b'c+ab $ stuck again

Comment: $ab+b'c$, is it impossible to get this?

Comment: @Vixf I fear, it may not be possible.

Comment: ok i got it form karnaugh map, and the most simplify one is $ab+b'c$ but suppose i circle the subcube that is not the most simplify one $ab+ac+a'b'c$, after simplified it using Boolean algebra right it suppose to have same answer with the most simplify one right?

Comment: @Vixf, yes you are right.

Comment: thanks!!, but is it impossible to reduce the variable from 3 to 2? or can i use demorgan?

Comment: @Vixf Note that it is possible only in some cases. Just like that, we cannot reduce a three variable expression into a two variable one, right?

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!! And I manage to find way to simplify itu to ab+b'c!!!